# Mocking behavior in python, only care about one of the parameters

Tags: python, mocking, assertions

I am using magic mock for some python testing that I am doing. There is a function

```
sendmail()
```

which looking at the source code, is defined like this

```
def sendmail(sender, 
         addrs, 
         subject, 
         body, 
         format               = 'plain', 
         cc                   = [], 
         bcc                  = [], 
         replyTo              = [],
         attach               = [], 
         useOutlook           = False,
         force                = False,  ## UNUSED!
         priority             = None,
         addStandardBobFooter = True
         ):
```

That much isn't really important. What I want my test to do is confirm that this is sending an email with the correct subject. So what I have done so far is...

```
sendmail = MagicMock()
self._fundingRollsPublisher.publish()  #this function contains a call to sendmail()
```

and inside the publish code, we have

```
def publish(): 

#much more code
sendmail(mail_from, mail_to, subject, body, format = 'html')
```

Sorry for the long winded explanation so far, but that is all the background knowledge. How would I confirm that the send mail function is being called with a given subject... say if I want the subject to be "URGENT", then I want to do something to the effect of

```
sendmail.assert_called_with(subject= "URGENT")
```

When I tried this, it didn't appear to work. Anyone know of a way to do it where you only care about one of the variables?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
class MagicMock:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def assert_subject(self, subject):
        assert len(self.args) > 2 and self.args[2] == subject) or self.kwargs.get('subject', None) == subject, "Unexpected subject"
```